# php upload image get undefined index for $_FILE['file'], also submit button is not detected as isset

Tags: php

I have have 2 files. one for image upload. one for evaluating. 
1st file:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Upload File</title></head>
  <body>
  <h2>Upload File</h2>
 <form method="post" action="Assignment7_backend.php" enctype="multipart/form­data"><input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='50000'>
 Your file: <input type="file" name="image">
 <br/> 
 <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

2nd file:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Upload File</title></head>
  <body>
  <h2>Upload File now</h2>
  <?php

  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    if($_FILES['image']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

      print "<p>File not uploaded successfully!</p>";
      print "<p><a href='Assignment7_upload.php'>Try Uploading Again</a> </p>" ;
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "./images/" . $_FILES['image']['name'] )
      or die("can't move file");
      print "<p>Success!</p>";
    }
  } else {
    print("<p>File is not uploaded</p>");
    print("<p>".$_FILES['image']['error']."</p>");
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      print("<p>cannot even detect submit</p>");
    }
  }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was hoping to upload the file, but after I choose the file and submit, it shows error: `$_FILE['image']` index is undefined. also, `$_POST['submit']` is not set. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try if(isset($_POST)) ?

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST);` in your *2nd file* and post the dump here

Comment: Well, you didn't give your submit button a `name` by which to be `POST`ed.

Comment: @MubinKhalid: Array ( [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 50000 [image] => test1.jpeg )

Comment: @underscore_d a name element is only needed when you reference your post by an identifier, else $_POST is just about enough to handle it all.

Comment: I think what @underscore_d meant was that the `isset` check for submit failed because it has no name, thus doesn't exist. Do check your max upload size and check if your `file_uploads=on` in php.ini.

Comment: @WilliamMadede:
good point, $_POST is not set. but how can i change it to be set. I've done other forms using php and it's always set.

Comment: @Wabbit0111 What happens when you do  if(isset($_POST)){ all your code}else{echo "Button not set;"} please post the outcome here

Comment: @WilliamMadede
Hi this is solved. there's a typo in the "enctype" in the form field. so that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enctype you posted here is wrong. So the form fails to submit any image/file.
I don't know if this is a typo or you actually have it wrong in your code.
The correct one is: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`